# Can't create a site collection through SharePoint Managment Shell for SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I tried to run the same commands as in here -https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263165(v=office.14).aspx .

```
 $template = Get-SPWebTemplate "STS#0"
New-SPSite -Url "http://web-application-name/sitecollection1" -OwnerAlias "domain\administrator" -Template $template
```

I am getting the following error:
*New-SPSite : A site collection could not be created as the provided managed pat
h does not exist.  Change the URL to use an existing managed path or create the
 missing managed path prior to calling this command.*

What does this error mean? What am i missing?

Comment: Before creating a Sitecollection you have create a managed Path. Syntax: New-SPManagedPath –RelativeURL "<Name>" -WebApplication "http://share
point2010/"

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it didn't work. I am still getting the same error after running: New-SPManagedPath -RelativeURL "sitecollection1" -WebApplic
ation "http://web-application-name". Maybe i am giving the wrong URI in New-SPSite command?

Comment: The web-application-name should include the protocol and host. Ensure that the (root) is set up to Wildcard Inclusion and not Explicit Inclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.$template = Get-SPWebTemplate "STS#0"

if you are getting error upon running this command use this link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2796733/sharepoint-2010-management-shell-does-not-load-with-windows-powershell-3.0
to fix it

2.Create a managed path

New-SPManagedPath -RelativeURL "sitecollection1" -WebApplic ation "web-application-name"

3.Create the site collection

New-SPSite -URL "http://web-application-name/**sites**/sitecollection1"-OwnerAlias "domain\administrator"  -Template $template

It is not very clear for my how to create a site collection with a path like:
http://web-application-name/sitecollection2
But this solution worked for what i needed.

Comment: If you want to create it without "sites", you have to have "(root)" use  "Wildcard Inclusion" instead of "Explicit Inclusion" like it does by default.  The way you do that is to go into Application Management and select the Web Application in Central Admin, then select Managed Paths. Delete the "(root)" one. Put a forward slash `/` in the textbox, select "Wildcard Inclusion" in the dropdown, select to "Add Path".  Then you can create a site collection on the root.  But one caveat, you can't use underscores or reserved words, like "my" in the path for the new site collection.

Comment: One thing with this answer, make `-WebApplic ation` be `-WebApplication`  . :)